# Enable login to one device at a time

Tags: java, android, authentication, oauth-2.0

When user install the app, we generate unique id on the app and store it.

User can login with user name and password. If login successful, server send OAuth token to app. App store the token and refresh tokens for future use.

But when user try to login from new device, I want to logout the user from previous phone.

How can I logout another device ?

(I want to delete the OAuth tokens from previous device. if not app try to refresh the token and allow user to login.)

Where I want to handle the logout logic ?
Any help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think accepted answer is a correct solution. You should not have this logic on client side. This could lead to potential security issues.

All you need to do is invalidate the old oauth token on the server side, so the next time the old device uses the old token it would receive, 400 invalid_grant exception, that's when you have to perform a log out.

Comment: yes. but then how do I know from which device user is login ?

Comment: Do I need to override OAuth login method ? if not OAuth give new token to same user. (two users can login at the same time)

Comment: Roshan, I don't know what is your implementation of oauth. I can not go into the details! The point is as long as you invalidate the old refresh token for the user account that logs in, only the latest will be active and when the other device tries to access api with the old token it would get logged out.

Comment: Thanks for change the direction. I override  the token view   TokenView(OAuthLibMixin, View) to delete the old tokens if the grant type is password.

Answer (score 1):

You can send a notification to the previously logged in device to remove the login. Or do a check in background every time the app starts, if the login is still valid in the server or another device logged in already. If another device already logged in don't let user get into the app and remove login credentials from the app.

Comment: So when user login from another device. after login successful I need to update the generate device id on separate call ? or make login with user name, password and device id ? bec in OAuth login I cannot pass device id.

Comment: Yeah, you need to update the device Id on a seperate call.

Comment: Can a user misuse the app by login programmatically make call to our backend ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but If the login credential is not valid, then it wont affect anything in your backend. When sending the deviceId to your database, also send some kind of token that will make sure that this user is properly logged in your system. This can be done when user request login to your server and  on successful validation, you generate, store and send a token back to the device.oAuth token serves the purpose of verying that account belongs the that user, and the new generated token willl mean that this user is in your system